# Is there some program that searches SuperUser for bad words in posts?

Tags: support, editing

Earlier tonight I posted something asking about MediaWiki and I tried to ask "how do I do that" but I accidentally typed "hoe do I do that".  I realized this because one of the site admins edited the post and changed that one letter.  I thought it was strange that they would have just happened across my post and change that one typo.

Is there software that runs on SuperUser that looks for bad words?

Comment: For reference: [privileges awarded based on reputation](http://superuser.com/privileges).

Comment: A "hoe" is a garden implement. Not really fodder for a naughty word filter.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there software that runs on SuperUser

No, there isn't - though you can always do a site specific search on Google.

FYI the question was edited by a user, [Nifle](https://superuser.com/users/2013/nifle) - he isn't a site admin or a Moderator. Super User is a collaboratively edited site and quite a lot of users often help in improving the site quality by [reviewing posts](https://superuser.com/review/). It's not "strange" that people comes across your post and change typos, it happens [a lot of times](https://superuser.com/users?tab=editors) and that's one of the most appealing features of Stack Exchange for me.

So to summarize - there's isn't a software that looks for bad words, but we do have lists for new posts that we tend to look at and it's not just the site admins who can edit - anyone can.